# how to fix the error: "INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found"?

Tags: java, hibernate

I tried to test whether the hibernate configuration is working properly. I tried but I got an error:

```
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
```

To do this: I create:

[1] hibernate configuration file [using xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">explorecalifornia</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">abc123</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[2] A hibernate utility class

```
public class HibernateUtilities {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static{
        try{
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }

        catch(HibernateException exception){
            System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateUtilities.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


}
```

[3] The main program:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;

    public class Program {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hibernate");

            Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.close();

        }

    }
```

But i got the following thing when I run the program:

```
Hibernate
Sep 29, 2013 10:47:15 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Sep 29, 2013 10:47:15 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.5.Final}
Sep 29, 2013 10:47:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 29, 2013 10:47:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Sep 29, 2013 10:47:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Sep 29, 2013 10:47:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Problem creating session factory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.simpleprogrammer.Program.main(Program.java:10)
```

To solve this I tried Google and apply the ways which i found. but still i could not solve the problem. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 20):

That's only an INFO message telling that you don't have a `hibernate.properties` file. This property file is not mandatory and so it's not what prevents your application from working.

If you want to know what caused the `SessionFactory` creation failure, you need to change your catch block to:

```
catch(HibernateException exception){
     System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");
     exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should use a logging framework instead.

Answer (score 5):

**Your problem is creation session Factory** for your application it happening in `HibernateUtilities` class , the reason may be due to , you cannot create a sessionfactory by `sessionRegistry` create it by hibernate Configuration class, because you registered your configuration in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Just Replace the following code in HibernateUtilities class

```
        `sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);`
```

to

```
        `sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();`
```

Comment: I replaced that line of code. when i run the program, I am getting the same error. "INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found"

Comment: Just remove the line `serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();` in `UtilitiesClass` because in that part only your strucking and getting exception, and your all other configuration is quiet good

Comment: I just tried your program, its working fine, did you set `properties file` in your console configuration , if yes, where you placed those.

Comment: no i dont set / use any properties file. Moreover, i only use the following jars to do this:  antlr-2.7.7.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was running the **Hibernate 5** with JPA annotations on tomcat and stop working when I changed to **glassfish 4.1**

The error:

**hibernate.properties not found**

**Make sure:**
src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml exists

And if you only have the dependency of hibernate-core, I was using hibernate-annotations and hibernate-common-annotations and it was creating conflict. The hibernate 5 doesnt need these two, I had read somewhere.Try to remove ;)

After that a new error appears:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V**

The reason was the oldest jboss-logging.jar at: "YOUR_GLASSFISH_FOLDER/glassfish/modules"

Why? The **hibernate 5** has dependency with the newest version of jboss-logging, and the **glassfish 4** uses the oldest version even if you declare inside your POM file the newest version. Actually I'm using:

```
org.jboss.logging jboss-logging 3.3.0.Final
```

Then I downloaded it and replace the old .jar inside the modules path and it back to work, I spent 2 days trying to solve that and I hope it helps some future issues =D

I used this link to help me: https://medium.com/@mertcal/using-hibernate-5-on-payara-cc242212a5d6#.npq2hdprz

**Another solution, in my case, could be back to the last Hibernate 4 version (4.3.11.Final) but it is already too old in my opinion**

Answer (score 1):

The configuration files must be placed in the classpath. Make  Sure that the hibernate.cfg.xml is in class-path. As your program is console program, u need to place that hibernate.cfg.xml in src folder. If u have placed it in other folder than specify it in `Confingure.configure(fileName);` 
And as answered By Mr.Kark u have to delete following lines

`serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

1. make sure that file hibernate.cfg.xml is located at src/main/resource
2. add pom.xml

```html
<!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
  </dependency>

<!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

It work for me

Comment: Thanks!! It worked for me as well after adding the above two dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some hibernate libs (maybe `hibernate-tools.jar` I guess). So please check it.

Anyway, I saw you using the hibernate annotations, so please try this code and see what happen with error properties not found.

```
try {
        AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();          
        sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**session-factory** is a special tag in hibernate it's have no any name so,
You can change your code **session-factory name=""** to **session-factory** and try to run.

Comment: Would you please tell me how to add sessions onto the application.properties?

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in hibernate.cfg.xml location.
Intellej IDEA created it in java folder.
I've replaced it into resources folder and it helped