# No more connection with c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I have connection issues since i decided to use c3p0 pooling.

persistence.xml

```
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://***.***.***.***:****/*****"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="****"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="****"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<!--            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" /> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1"/> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="50"/> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="10000"/> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="100"/> -->
<!--            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/> -->
```

With this config everything works fine. When i uncomment the c3p0 properties i cant even connect to my application.

```
try {               
    user = UserDAO.connect(login,Tools.encode(password));
}
 catch (SQLException e) {   
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.error(utils.Constants.GENERAL_ERROR);
    message=utils.Constants.LOGIN_KO;
}
finally{
//some code
}
```

I tried to run this code in debug. I have a break point on each block. The program directly go from the try to the finally.
Here are the logs:

```
2015-08-26 15:27:50 INFO  LogHelper:46 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: ****
...]
2015-08-26 15:27:53 INFO  Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
2015-08-26 15:27:53 INFO  Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-08-26 15:27:53 INFO  Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-08-26 15:27:56 INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-08-26 15:27:56 INFO  ConnectionProviderInitiator:190 - HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
2015-08-26 15:27:56 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:117 - HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://***.***.***.***:****/*****
2015-08-26 15:27:56 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:118 - HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=****, password=****}
2015-08-26 15:27:56 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:121 - HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
```

I see there is this line in the logs

```
Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
```

But i dont understand where it comes from and if it is the reason of the issue.
I already looked at 
[how to fix the error: "INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085816/how-to-fix-the-error-info-hhh000206-hibernate-properties-not-found)
and similar posts

@Maciej Dobrowolski
I dont use Maven so i dont have pom.xml (i wont explain why here it is not related)
Here are the jars i have in the classpath:

```
 /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-c3p0-5.0.0.Final.jar
 /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
 /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar
 /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar
 /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
 /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar
```

Comment: if everything works fine in the default configuration, why did you change it?

Comment: i need to add c3p0 for the pooling properties

Comment: Not founding `hibernate.properties` is not a problem since you use `persistence.xml` to define your properties. File called `hibernate.properties` is not found, so there is a message in console. That's all.

Comment: Can you also post content of your `pom.xml` file? I mean the lines related to hibernate and c3p0

Answer (score 0):

It could be silly but i think you need to add:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

to your configuration, i hope this works for you,

Comment: Im sorry but i cant test your answer. If it works for other people and they upvote you, i ll validate the answer