# Database table not creating

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have created a separate utility class for SessionFactory and below is my code:

```
        package com.Hibernate.Util;

        import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
        import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
        import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
        import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

        public class HibernateUtil {
            private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
            private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
                try {
                    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
                    System.out.println("Hibernate configuration loading......");
                    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
                    System.out.println("Hibernate serviceRegistry created.....");
                    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
                    return sessionFactory;
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    System.out.println("SessionFactory creation failure.....");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
                }
            }
            public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory1() {
                if (sessionFactory == null)
                    sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
                return sessionFactory;
            }
        }
```

Hibernate configuration file
        **hibernate.cfg.xml file**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
     <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>    
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>    
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root.123</property>    
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hibernate</property>    
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>   
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>    
            <mapping class="com.Hibernate.Model.Employee"></mapping>
            <mapping class="com.Hibernate.Model.Address"></mapping>
       </session-factory> 
     </hibernate-configuration>
```

Below class calls the SessionFactory method buildSessionFactory
    **HQLExample.java**:

```
package com.Hibernate.Main;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.Hibernate.Model.Employee;
import com.Hibernate.Util.HibernateUtil;

public class HQLExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory1();
        System.out.println(sessionFactory);
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

The code is executing but the tables are being not created.
Can someone please tell me what would be the issue with the code???

Comment: I didnt quite get your question??what exactly do you mean by table not getting created?

Comment: I have created two Entity class: Employee and Address. The classes have been mapped to the hibernate.cfg.xml file. But while executing the Main class there needs to be creation of two table, but in my case no table are not creating. I don't know what exactly is going wrong. Please help me out as I am new to Hibernate technology.

Comment: Can please check in logs, is there any create query ? Why I'm asking as I can see you enabled show_sql in xml config and might be access issue

Comment: I can see any create query statement in log, but there some statement like hibernate.properties not found                                                                INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
Mar 06, 2017 3:37:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
If following statement is added then table is created in database:                                             SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

Comment: If no exception/error then only guess might be you should specify MySQL5InnoDBDialect instead of MySQLDialect if your mysql not prior version 5.x [DOC](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)

Comment: Changed to MySQL5InnoDBDialect but still the table is not created.

Comment: Please have a look into this issue [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085816](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085816/how-to-fix-the-error-info-hhh000206-hibernate-properties-not-found)

Comment: The issue is with the hibernate.cfg.xml file. It is not mapping the classes Employee and Address even though including it into the file.                                     <mapping class="com.Hibernate.Model.Employee"></mapping>
<mapping class="com.Hibernate.Model.Address"></mapping>                         Any idea how to map the classes?

Comment: The file hibernate.cfg.xml is placed at src/main/resources location of the project.

Comment: hey, I meet the same situation

Answer (score 0):

Please update the main method using the below codebase in HQLExample.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory1();
        System.out.println(sessionFactory);
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   try {
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            transaction.commit();
            System.out.println("Database tables created successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error to creating database tables for hibernate file : "+ e.getMessage());
        }finally {
           sessionFactory.close();
           session.close();
        }
    }
```