# Getting Error:INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, jdbc, hibernate-mapping

I am eclipse IDE..
I have configured hibernate properly but still i am getting this error.

Directory Structure:

HibernateProject-Java Resources-Src

> -com.project    -Employeee.java    -Testjdbc.java(contains main function)
>   -hibernate.cfg.xml

Employee.java

```
package com.package;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="employeee")
public class Employeee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Empcode")
      private int Empcode;
    @Column(name="EmpName")
      private String EmpName;
    @Column(name="EmpDesignation")
      private String EmpDesignation;
    @Column(name="EmpDOB")
      private Date EmpDOB;
    @Column(name="EmpJOD")
      private Date EmpJOD;
    @Column(name="EmpAge")
      private int EmpAge;
    @Column(name="EmpBasic_Pay")
      private double EmpBasic_Pay;
    public int getEmpcode() {
        return Empcode;
    }
    public void setEmpcode(int empcode) {
        Empcode = empcode;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return EmpName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        EmpName = empName;
    }
    public String getEmpDesignation() {
        return EmpDesignation;
    }
    public void setEmpDesignation(String empDesignation) {
        EmpDesignation = empDesignation;
    }
    public Date getEmpDOB() {
        return EmpDOB;
    }
    public void setEmpDOB(Date empDOB) {
        EmpDOB = empDOB;
    }
    public Date getEmpJOD() {
        return EmpJOD;
    }
    public void setEmpJOD(Date empJOD) {
        EmpJOD = empJOD;
    }
    public int getEmpAge() {
        return EmpAge;
    }
    public void setEmpAge(int empAge) {
        EmpAge = empAge;
    }
    public double getEmpBasic_Pay() {
        return EmpBasic_Pay;
    }
    public void setEmpBasic_Pay(double empBasic_Pay) {
        EmpBasic_Pay = empBasic_Pay;
    }

    public Employeee() {

    }
    public Employeee(int empcode, String empName, String empDesignation, java.util.Date sdate, java.util.Date edate, int empAge,
            double empBasic_Pay) {
        super();
        Empcode = empcode;
        EmpName = empName;
        EmpDesignation = empDesignation;
        EmpDOB = sdate;
        EmpJOD = edate;
        EmpAge = empAge;
        EmpBasic_Pay = empBasic_Pay;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [Empcode=" + Empcode + ", EmpName=" + EmpName + ", EmpDesignation=" + EmpDesignation
                + ", EmpDOB=" + EmpDOB + ", EmpJOD=" + EmpJOD + ", EmpAge=" + EmpAge + ", EmpBasic_Pay=" + EmpBasic_Pay
                + "]";
    }

}
```

Testjdbc.java

```
package com.package;




import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.wipro.Employeee;

public class TestJDBC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                .addAnnotatedClass(Employeee.class)
                                .buildSessionFactory();

        // create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {           
            // create a student object
            System.out.println("Creating new student object...");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            java.util.Date sdate=sdf.parse("2018/07/22");
            java.util.Date edate=sdf.parse("2019/07/22");
            //empcode empName empDesignation empDOB empJOD empAge empBasic_Pay;
            Employeee emp=new Employeee(101,"ABC","Engineer",sdate,edate,25,250000.00);

            // start a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            // save the student object
            System.out.println("Saving the student...");
            session.save(emp);

            // commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("Done!");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbcassignment?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">tiger</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Error:

```
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.1.Final}
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbcassignment?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
Aug 25, 2018 6:13:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.wipro.TestJDBC.main(TestJDBC.java:23)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more
```

Please see if you can help.

Comment: Adding the full error message / stacktrace would it make much easier to help you. Nevertheless it sounds a little bit like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085816/how-to-fix-the-error-info-hhh000206-hibernate-properties-not-found

Comment: Edited.. Please check

Comment: The INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found is only an informational message - no error. The real problem is the SQLNonTransientConnectionException.Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379839/connnection-java-mysql-public-key-retrieval-is-not-allowedth

Comment: its not helping.. can you please help if u can

Comment: Did you try to add this client option to your mysql-connector **allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true**?

Comment: actually i didnt understood where to add this.. in jar file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178740/discussion-between-vjain-and-weizenkeim-hugo).